# Display day of week based on int stored in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, haml, dayofweek, fields-for

i have a list trading hours stored in my database, and have elected to use int for the weekdays. i am now trying to loop through the code to be able to display a form that will allow the user to update the trading hours for a given day though i am having trouble getting the int for day of the week to be displayed as a string

```
= form.fields_for :trading_hours do |hours_fields|
  %li.mdl-list__item.mdl-list__item--two-line
    %span.mdl-list__item-primary-content
      = hours_fields.label= Date::DAYNAMES[hours_fields.weekday]
      %span.mdl-list__item-sub-title
        = hours_fields.time_select :open_time, {:default => {:hour => '9', :minute => '00'}, :minute_step => 15, :ampm => true}
        \-
        = hours_fields.time_select :close_time, {:default => {:hour => '17', :minute => '00'}, :minute_step => 15, :ampm => true}
    %span.mdl-list__item-secondary-action
      %label.mdl-checkbox.mdl-js-checkbox.mdl-js-ripple-effect{:for => hours_fields}
        = hours_fields.check_box :trades, :class => 'mdl-checkbox__input', :id => hours_fields
```

trading hours model

```
class TradingHour < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :merchant

  scope :open_now, -> (day, time) do
    where('weekday = ? AND open_time <= ? AND close_time > ?', day, time, time)
  end
end
```

Comment: What values are in `hours_fields.weekday`?

Comment: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 where each int represents a day of the week

Comment: What you have should work

Comment: i get `undefined method `weekday' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007f9c4fad2ee0>`

Comment: Can you post your `TradingHours` model please

Answer (score 0):

You have two `=` on the same line. Nest the DAYNAMES line.

```
= hours_fields.label
  = Date::DAYNAMES[hours_fields.weekday]
```